# How can I get a dataset annotated with Jobtitles?

Tags: nlp, entity, named

I need it to do some entity extraction. How do I get an annotated dataset with `JobTitles`?

Comment: Did you do any research or experimentation yourself first?  This question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: Yes but I didn't find anything.

Comment: It is not clear what type of dataset do you want. Do you need a list with jobTitles? Or do you need a rawtext where job titles are manually annoteted?

Comment: Ok...what is Jobtitles?  What entities are you trying to extract?  Again...this question needs specifics for people to help you.

Comment: I need rawtext where jobs titles are annotated

Comment: Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can find data where occupations are also annotated: http://nlp.uned.es/weps/weps-2/weps2-papers

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest to do, if you haven't come across any datasets. Grab wikipedia occupation lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_occupations, create a gazetteer list of jobs and write regular expressions to capture them or any variations in the text and you have annotated data :).

Comment: Or she can build a corpus from the wikipedia: when a link in a random wiki  page link to one of the occupation Wiki page she found an occupation in raw text.